# How to update NTP (Network Time Protocol) on Solaris 11? Fighting with DDoS attacks

Tags: software-installation, solaris, ntp

At the moment lots of servers suffers from denial of service attacks targeting NTP protocol on port 123 by issuing `MONLIST` requests to victims computers. Victims computers answer with large list of last NTP clients. Thus consuming a lot of network bandwidth. It is possible to restrict `MONLIST` response by adding these lines to `ntp.conf` file:

```
restrict -4 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
restrict -6 default nomodify nopeer noquery notrap
restrict source nomodify noquery notrap
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

This is good on installed NTP version 4.2.5.200 (4.2.5p200). I found that on newer versions - starting from 4.2.6 `MONLIST` is replaced by safer `MRUNLIST`.

I'm trying to update NTP on Solaris 11 machine by issuing command `pkg update ntp`, but it seems that on Oracle repository only version 4.2.5 is available.

I found newer version 4.2.8p6 at http://www.ntp.org/downloads.html.
So my question is - how to install this new NTP version on Solaris 11? It is not a Solaris package.

Answer (score 2):

NTP 4.2.8p2 is included if you upgrade to Solaris 11.3, the currently supported version of Solaris 11.

Comment: If I upgrade it to Solaris 11.3 version - like it is explained [here](http://www.unixarena.com/2014/08/upgrade-oracle-solaris-11-1-oracle-solaris-11-2.html) - do I have to back up the files located at `/opt` directory?

Comment: It appears the procedure on that site is following the vendor's procedure for the upgrade.  When in doubt, refer to Oracles procedure.

When creating a new boot environment as part of the upgrade, everything should carry over.  You can always mount a different BE to verify.